# hive:select all column exclude two

Tags: sql, hive

How to select all column exclude columns 'date' and 'cst_id' in hive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below -

For single session - `set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;`

```
select `(date|cst_id)?+.+` from myTable.
```

refer [quotedIdentifiers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.support.quoted.identifiers) for more information on hive select using regular expressions

Comment: For Spark SQL: `set spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true;`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer and the example regex on the hive manual page is flawed. If you want to exclude two columns `day` and `day_hour`, `(day|day_hour)?+.+` will still match `day_hour` column. That's because regex engine is eager on `|`. Although changing the order to `(day_hour|day)?+.+` can solve this issue, the better method is using negative lookahead, `(?!(day|day_hour)$).+`.